# Any idea how can i monitor a function's progress (Not for a Loop)?

Tags: r

For eg i have following dfs

```
a <- mtcars
b <- aggregate(cyl ~ mpg , data = a , sum)
```

I want to monitor how much progress this aggregate function has made while it performs .
Any idea ?

Comment: You can check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progress/progress.pdf)

Comment: Be warned that adding progress bars can substantially increase calculation time, which if it is already long enough to warrant a progress bar is going to be very undesirable.

Comment: @akrun : Thanks for the hint . . but i want to add it into a function as shown above,  not in a loop . I was just wondering if there is any way this could be done for a standalone function itself.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look a the new waiter package: https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter